# I know that electrons possess a magnetic moment so how can I calculate how attracted they will be to a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

I know that electrons possess a magnetic moment so how can I calculate how attracted they will be to a magnetic field?, of a specified strengths in Gauss.

Answer (score 1):

The only force a magnetic dipole (moment) experiences in a uniform magnetic field is a torque: a force that tends to align the  dipole moment with the direction of the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

There energy of a magnetic moment, $\vec{\mu}$, in an external field, $\vec B$, is:

$$U = -\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B} $$

In a static field there is no position dependence to the energy, thus there is no force. The dot product indicates the energy depends on the relative orientation of the moment and the field: hence, there is a torque.

If $\vec B$ is not unform, then:

$$ \vec F = -\nabla\vec U = \nabla(\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}) = (\vec{\mu}\cdot\nabla)\vec B $$

If the field is time varying, you include a term from the curl:

$$ \vec F = (\vec{\mu}\cdot\nabla)\vec B + \vec{\mu} \times (\nabla \times \vec B)=\nabla(\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec B)$$